# NoClassDefFoundError only for specific class in EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Below is the ear structure

```
ex.ear
|
|_lib-util.jar--CommonUtil.class,CommonException.class etc.
|
|
|
ejb.jar
web.war
```

When I call this specific class like this (`CommonUtil.map(empDto)`) in WEB and EJB layer classes then we are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  Remaining all classes which are in Util.jar are all getting called normally.  Why are we getting this error only for this class?

```
EmployeeDTO empDto = new EmployeeDTO();
empDto.setId(1);
empDto.setName("john");
CommonUtil.map(empDto);
```

```java
public class CommonUtil {

    private static Mapper mapper = new BeanMapper();
    private static CommonUtil instance = new CommonUtil();

    private CommonUtil() {
        super();
    }

    public static <T> T map(Object source) {
        T target = mapper.map(source);
        return target;
    }

    public static <T> T map(Object source) {
        mapper.map(source);
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: some system information might help...

Comment: am deploying this ear in glassfish server in my local windows system.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the message in the `NoClassDefFoundError`?  There are three reasons (at least) why this exception can be thrown: class can't be found, class-file contains wrong name, class has already failed static initialization.

Comment: Which are imports for EmployeeDTO and CommonUtil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the `NoClassDefFoundError` happens if an Exception occurs during the static initialization. Please check the log prior `NoClassDefFoundError` carefully if any exception happened during instantiating `BeanMapper` or `CommonUtil`.